# Выбор кода в соответствии с окружением

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Реакт приложение. Некоторые контейнеры могут получать данные из сети. Для этого использован React.Context и мой App обернут в Provider из этого контектса.
Вот так:

```
<Provider value={new MyService}><App/></Provider>
```

В зависимости от конфигурации релиз/дебаг, я хочу в value Provider разные объекты

Например:

```
value={DEBUG ? new DummyMyService : new MyService}
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как этого достичь? Использую create-react-app

Answer (score 0):

```
value={process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production" ? new DummyMyService : new MyService}
```

В вообще, создавать сервисы в render'е - так себе идея.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Почему идея так себе? И почему вы используете окружение ноды, через process? Этот же код будет выполняться в браузере, где process не определен

Comment: 1. Потому что render может вызываться многократно. 2. Вебпак должен при компиляции подставить и потом выкинуть лишнюю ветку.